# Get all files except .zip

Tags: c#, file, loops, zip

This maybe a simple question, but how do i get all files in a folder except the `.zip` extension. I have a `foreach` loop as follow :

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directories)
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles("*.*"))
    {
    }
}
```

Should I do an `if` statement inside second loop and check `if (file.Name.contains("zip")) then continue` or is there a better way?

Comment: The problem with that is you'd be excluding zip.txt.

Comment: oops yes i didn't consider that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FileInfo` has a property `Extension` which will give you the string representing of the extension for each file.

**Edit:**
You can use this LINQ query to simplify your code:

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = directory.GetFiles("*.*").Where(file => !string.Equals(file.Extension, ".zip", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: unfortunately cannot use linq as it is framework 2.0 but your first suggestion did the trick. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

In .NET 4.0 onwards, you can use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx):

```
List<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\temp", "*.*", 
                                              SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                       .Where(n => Path.GetExtension(n) != ".txt").ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

don't check for zip in name. Use `FileInfo.Extension` or Pass name in `Path.GetExtension(filename)` it should not be `.zip`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
public staticList<FileInfo> GetFiles(string folder, string includeMask, string     excludeMask, SortOrder sortOrder, SearchOption searchOption)
{
DirectoryInfo folderDirectoryInfo = newDirectoryInfo(folder);
List<FileInfo> files = newList<FileInfo>(folderDirectoryInfo.GetFiles(includeMask,  searchOption));

stringexcludeMaskRegEx = FileSystemHelper.WildcardToRegex(excludeMask);
// exclude files
files = (fromfile infiles
         where!Regex.IsMatch(file.Name, excludeMaskRegEx) 
         selectfile).ToList<FileInfo>();
if(files.Count > 0)
{
    switch(sortOrder)
    {
        //somecode
    }
  }
  returnfiles;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ:

```
static List<string> GetNonZipFiles(string path)
        {
            return Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(x => !x.EndsWith(".zip")).ToList();
        }
```